# How to instantiate and visualize elements in AnyLogic using a Java class?

Tags: java, instantiation, anylogic

I would like to instantiate a simulation Elements in AnyLogic through a Java class and visualize them on the simulation workspace, such as generating an element from the Process Modeling Library, like "Queue". I couldn't find the relevant constructor in the AnyLogic development documentation. I would like to ask if this idea can be realized? If so, could you please tell me how to do it and provide a simple demo? If not, could you please explain the reasons you know? Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "agent-ify" a Queue, create an agent type, drag in a queue, add ports to the left and right and instantiate that.

Or (even simpler) drag a Queue on Main, right-click it and select "Create flow chart block":
[image]

There is no need to use Java classes for something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried your method and successfully built a  simple production system using functions and Agents: Source->Queue->Delay1->Delay2->Sink. But I still want to know if this process can be achieved by developing a Java Class in Anylogic or in external IDE. I have searched a lot of information but couldn't find the answer. Could you please let me know if my idea is feasible? Thank you very much for your professional knowledge.

Comment: You can code anything yourself. These building blocks are just helpers to avoid that. It gets tricky fast if you want to do time-based things, this is what agents are for....

Suggest you come up with a specific problem that you are trying to solve.

Else, just learn about Java coding and write Java classes, if you desire

Comment: Okay, I understand now and have a better understanding of the relationship between Java coding and building simulation models. Thank you very much for your answer. It has been very helpful to me.